# How to get NearByLocations(possible addresses) on current Location in IOS from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.windows

**I have problem with getting NearByPlaces to the current location in xamarin.Forms in GoogleMaps.please the below link , In this link I have explained the issue in the Comment section. and If any knows the solution let me know the solution.**

https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-maps/#comment-1434

Comment: I can't test with your incomplete code , and by the way why don't you use `Forms.Maps` following this sample :https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/ ?

Comment: I have already used which you said "Forms.maps", Here, I have given link which is full project, You can test it.and you can the difference in list-of_addresses both platforms Android & IOS.                                                                      
                                                                    
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwa64gz3KvzGeFI0VnVTOWVtSDQ

Comment: There are several build  errors, can you check it to make it  run successfully.